# java casting a list

Tags: java, generics, list

Let's say I had:

```
protected void performLogic(List<Object> docs) {
  ...
}
```

In the code where I'm going to be calling this method, I have a `List<String>` list. I want to call performLogic, passing this list. But it won't work because the lists are 2 different types:

```
public void execute() {
    List<String> docs = new ArrayList<String>();
    performLogin(docs);  // won't work
}
```

I tried casting to `List<Object>` also, but that won't work either.

So is the only way to do this is to make a new `ArrayList` of `Object` and just add the values and then pass it? Just seems cumbersome. I wondered if there was a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: do you control the code for performLogic()? If so change it to take a List<String> or better yet, change it to be generified and take a Type instead. Usually a different Type of list will require different logic.

Comment: No, it's part of a public API I cannot change.

Comment: That is a really bad API design. A better way would be to create a Facade and do then delegate to the bad API.

Comment: as others have pointed out, that signature performLogic(List<Object> docs) is bad design, specially for a public API. 
it practically forces the user to bypass the typesafety that generics provide.

Comment: Everyone is knee-jerking to say that `List<Object>` is a bad design. It is _probably_ the wrong type, but if this is a method that needs to _add_ objects of various types (with no common supertype) to that list, then it's the correct type for that. (Of course, that in itself is probably a bad design. :-))

Comment: what do you suggest the OP do then? create various different methods doing nearly the same thing but with onoly the param type different? That is more of a bad code design as the OP will be duplicating a lot of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work as well (though bypassing typesafety):

```
performLogic((List)docs);
```

Comment: -1 Completely ignoring the real issue!  I would unaccept this answer.

Comment: @Kevin - If by "the real issue" you mean that the API is badly designed, I think that has already been covered.  If he has to use the badly designed API, this is one possible way to do it.  Its ugly, but sometimes using other people's APIs is necessarily ugly.

Comment: @Kevin in the real world sometimes you have to use badly designed APIs.  The question asker clearly stated that this is a 3rd party API that he doesn't not have the ability to change.

Comment: I'm very sorry, then.  The question should have been edited -- one shouldn't have to read all the comments just to understand what's being asked. Still, I'd like to remove my downvote, but it appears I'm not allowed.

Comment: (Actually, as far as I know, that comment may not have even been there when I downvoted, so I partially de-apologize. :-))

Answer (score 3):

Its silly but you have to say T extends Object

```
protected static <T extends Object> void performLogic(List<T> docs)
```

Oh and its if part of a public API you can do this trick:

```
performLogic((List) var);
```

Just be careful as it will fail during runtime if var isn't an List of `Object`s.  But lucky for you it is.

Comment: I can't change signature of performLogic, it's part of a provided API.

Comment: Since all java classes are derived from Object, it's IMO not possible for the cast to fail at runtime.

Comment: @Michael - +1, the real risk is that "performLogic" could try to add a non-String.  If he knows that can't happen, that risk is mitigated.

Comment: @Michael my point is that in other cases you can create runtime failures if you are not careful.  IE.  It is generally dangerous to do this

Answer (score 3):

I think having `List<Object>` is a bad pattern since it really isn't that much better than `List` without generics. Generics are useful when you want to enforce type-safety in complex objects. As such they are really useful for enforcing type-safety in data structures.

You need to look at your algorithm and decide if you really want to accept a list of `Object`. That aside,  can also forcibly cast it, but then you would be completely disregarding type safety.

Comment: I'm voting this up just b/c it is the theoretically right solution.  Keep in mind that its not possible given the preconditions of the question, tough.

Comment: @jsight, I didn't notice that he said this was a 3rd-party API (he noted it in the comments but not in the question). Thanks for pointing that out to me, though.

Comment: I don't think List<Object> is exactly a "bad pattern"; it's just very rarely what you want. It means "a List I can put any kind of object into."  It is much different from raw "List", which essentially should _never_ be used.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But I also think it's very rare that you'd want to have a list into which you can insert any object. Not saying that there aren't those cases, but you probably have to think really hard if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not add elements to the docs, you can change API to

```
protected void performLogic(List<?> docs);
```

All previous code that uses `performLogic` will continue to compile.

Answer (score 1):

If the list doesn't need to be modified within `performLogic` you can use `Collections.unmodifiableList` to safely cast the list. Ex:

```
performLogic(Collections.unmodifiableList(docs));
```

To understand why this works you have to first understand why you can't just pass in docs as-is. The reason for that is a List can have any instance of object added to it (for instance an Integer). If the List reference were used later there would be an error because the Integer added to the list couldn't be cast to String. Making the list unmodifiable prevents this possibility so it is then safe to pass an unmodifiable List as a List.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be to try and have that broken API fixed. Using `List<Object>` as parameter is simply a misuse of Generics.

Until the API improves, you can cast to the raw type:

```
performLogin((List)docs);
```

It will still result in a compiler warning, though.

Comment: Correcting the broken API that the OP does not have access to is not an option, so there is no reason to comment about it.

Comment: @pcm2a: "it's not my code" doesn't mean you can't at least contact the people whose code it is and point out the flaw - especially since the fix is downwards-compatible. Sometimes people do listen, you know?

Comment: +1 I appreciate Michael's emphasis on this avenue of solution.  Also, the third-party nature of the API is not even mentioned in the question, only in a comment.